# How do I search a file then output a line with the keyword searched to a new file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to search a large file with a keyword in perl, then output ALL the lines the keyword appears in, each into a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will print all lines containing `keyword` to `outputFile.txt`. The input files are **passed as arguments** to the script.

**findkeyword.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open OUTPUT, ">outputFile.txt"; 
while (my $line = <>) {
     if($line =~ m/keyword/){
     print OUTPUT $line;
     }
}
```

**Input**:

```
./findkeyword.pl inputfile1 inputfile2 ...
```

---

**Edit:** As said by @Kenosis in the comments,

It might be better to use a lexically scoped $fh as file-handle like `open(my $fh, ">", "outputFile.txt")`. **Reference: [`open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)**

If you are storing keyword in a variable, you might want to call **[`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)** on it first, or enclose it in `\Q...\E`.

Comment: ok, i've got the script running, but I can't open my input files?

Comment: @user1597452 Are you giving the argument list to your script correctly? Any errors?

Comment: @Cthulhu - Why not a three-argument `open` w/a lexically-scoped fh?  Also, might `m/\Qkeyword\E/` help avoid any special chars in "keyword"?

Comment: @Kenosis The `<>` operator was concise and allowed for multiple files with least effort :). `\Q...\E` or `quotemeta`, I'll mention that. Thanks

Comment: @Cthulhu - Sorry...  I meant for the output file.  The `<>` does make much sense.  Thanks!